# JIRA REST API jql expression to search by standard issue types

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using the following query in the JIRA REST API to get all the issues of an sprint, by sprint id:

```
GET /api/latest/search?jql=Sprint=2131
```

However, that returns all the issues but I'm only interested in standard types but not sub-types as sub-task, sub-bug, etc.

Looking to the "Search" option in the JIRA GUI I have seen the following expression that probably suffices:

```
issuetype in standardIssueTypes()
```

However, I'm not sure how to apply that to the `jql=` parameter in the REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you see.

```
GET [host]/rest/api/latest/search?jql=issuetype%20in%20standardIssueTypes()
```

or

```
POST [host]/rest/api/latest/search

Body:

{
    "jql": "issuetype in standardIssueTypes()"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple add `issuetype in standardIssueTypes()` by using `AND` condition:

`jql=sprint=2131 and issuetype in standardIssueTypes()`